# regex to lazy match possible empty string

Tags: ruby, regex

I'd like to get anything between `A=[` and first enclosing `]`:

```
> str = "Hello A=[apple] B=[boy] World"
> str.match(/A=\[(.+?)\]/)[1]
 => "apple"
```

So far so good.

However, for `A=[]`:

```
> str = "Hello A=[] B=[boy] World"
> str.match(/A=\[(.+?)\]/)[1]
 => "] B=[boy"
```

How can I get a empty string `""`, instead of `"] B=[boy"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.*?` rather than `.+?`. The former matches zero or more characters, while the latter matches one or more.

```
"Hello A=[] B=[boy] World".match(/A*=*\[(.*?)\]/)[1] # => ""
```

Comment: Ah! How can I forget that? ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'd use:

```
str = "Hello A=[apple] B=[boy] World"
str[/A=\[(.*?)\]/, 1] # => "apple"
str = "Hello A=[] B=[boy] World"
str[/A=\[(.*?)\]/, 1] # => ""
```

I'm not sure why you're using `A*=*`, because it means "zero or more 'A' followed by zero or more '='" and basically fails to do anything useful, and, in fact, actually opens up a hole to return bad results. See the additional information in the edit below.

Here are variations on the same themes. All are documented in the [Regexp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html) and [`String.[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) documentation:

```
str = "Hello A=[apple] B=[boy] World"
str[/A=\[(.*?)\]/, 1] # => "apple"

/A=\[(.*?)\]/ =~ str 
$1 # => "apple"

str =~ /A=\[(.*?)\]/
$1 # => "apple"

/A=\[(?<in_brackets>.*?)\]/ =~ str
in_brackets # => "apple"

str = "Hello A=[] B=[boy] World"
str[/A=\[(.*?)\]/, 1] # => ""

/A=\[(.*?)\]/ =~ str 
$1 # => ""

/A=\[(?<in_brackets>.*?)\]/ =~ str 
in_brackets # => ""
```

---

> the *=* was intended to match possible space characters before or after the equal sign, e.g. str = "Hello A= [] B=[boy] World"

Well, `*=*` isn't how you should do it. You need to tell the regex engine what is optional:

```
/A *= */
```

would be correct, as would:

```
/A ?= ?/
```

Here's some tests to show you what's happening:

```
str = "Hello [foo] A = [apple] B=[boy] World"
str[/A*=*\[(.*?)\]/, 1] # => "foo"
str[/A *=*\[(.*?)\]/, 1] # => nil
str[/A *= *\[(.*?)\]/, 1] # => "apple"
str[/A ?= ?\[(.*?)\]/, 1] # => "apple"
```

Notice that your pattern `/A*=*/` allows the engine to match `[foo]`, not `A = [apple]`. This is because you're telling it to match no `A` and no `=` as an option, which opens the hole to grab `[foo]`. As long as your inputs are exactly two options, with no preceding value inside brackets you'll be safe. If you have an input with that your result will be wrong.

---

> `str[/A.*=.*\[(.*?)\]/,1]?`

Nope:

```
str = "Hello A=[apple] B=[boy] World"
str[/A.*=.*\[(.*?)\]/,1] # => "boy"
```

I'd recommend exploring how to use regex via [Rubular](http://rubular.com). Here's [a link showing the above example](http://rubular.com/r/MBsLuPkUUl) and why it fails.

Comment: the square bracket syntax is nice looking.

Comment: the `*=*` was intended to match possible space characters before or after the equal sign, e.g. `str = "Hello A= [] B=[boy] World"`.

Comment: Then you should document those in your example strings. And, `A*=*` won't work for possible spaces so any answer using them will be wrong. See the edit in my answer for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the `/A *= */` fix. I've edited the question to clarify it.